# jQuery value to name

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I have a dropdown called `#selected_studio`. In that drop one I have a `<option>` with `value="studio_17` and says `Testing...` if you look at the drop down in the browser. I want to read the "Testing..." text no matter if selected or not, just by knowing the value. I attempted to write some JS but it failed and not sure how it should be.

```
$("#selected_studio option:studio_17").text();
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I think it's possible. I'm using jQuery 1.7 if that's any helpful.

The full HTML:

```
<select id="selected_studio">
      <option value="me">Kevin</option>
      <option value="studio_17">Testing...</option>
      <option value="null" disabled="disabled">------------------------</option>
      <option value="new_studio">Studio Application</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#selected_studio option[value='studio_17']").text();
```

This uses the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#selected_studio option[value='studio_17']").text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$("#selected_studio option[value='studio_17']").text();
```